# Perpendicular vectors in $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: 3d, rotations

Hi I am struggling with this simple question. Let $\vec{v}$ be a unit vector in $\Bbb R^3$.

How can I construct two periodic functions $\vec{x}(\theta)$ $\vec{y}(\theta)$

such that $\vec{v}$,  $\vec{x}(\theta)$ and  $\vec{y}(\theta)$ are all perpendicular to each other, for all $\theta\in R$ ?

pic: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/Euler_AxisAngle.png/800px-Euler_AxisAngle.png

Comment: Construct the orthogonal plane of $v$ and then in that plane construct your periodic orthogonal vectors!

Comment: What if the v vector was in the k axis, you could generate x and y as x=cos*i + sin*j, and y=-sin*i + cos*j .   Now apply the 3-D general rotation matrix to all three vectors - how's that?

Comment: You have $u$ fixed. Find $x,y$ such that $u,x,y$ are perpedicular to each other. Now find the line that passes from the origin and is perpedicular in $u$. If you let $\theta$ to take values from that line then find the $u(\theta)$ (it's just a transposition of $u$) and there find $x(\theta),y(\theta)$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)^T$, take $x_0=(-v_2,v_1,0)$ and [$y_0=v\times x_0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Matrix_notation) and rotate 
\begin{align}
x(\theta)&=R(\theta)x_0,\\
y(\theta)&=R(\theta)y_0
\end{align}
with [Rodrigues' rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle).